# ASP:Login <LayoutTemplate> always generates a <table>, how can I make it stop?

Tags: asp.net

I've just started tinkering with the ASP:Login control, and want to edit its appearance. So I did the following:

```
<asp:login ID="login" runat="server" onauthenticate="Authenticate">
 <LayoutTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
 </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:login>
```

Despite the fact that I have no `<table>` tag anywhere in the document, once I preview the page and view the source, it very clearly shows a `<table>` there. Ah! How in the world do I prevent this crazy behavior, or am I forced to use tables for layout instead of CSS?

Answer (score 17):

You can set it not to use tables without third party extensions, just make sure you use the

```
<LayoutTemplate>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

For laying out your HTML/form inside the control, then set the attribute on the Login that controls the outer table to false.

```
RenderOuterTable="false"
```

That's it, no tables :)

Comment: Note that you need .Net 4.0+

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS Friendly control adapter for the login control to change it.

http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Membership/Login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things you can do.

The easiest would be to use the [Css Control Adapters toolkit](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/)'s version of the [Login control](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Membership/Login.aspx), although it hasn't been updated in a while and I haven't used it recently, so maybe it's not a great option anymore, I'm not sure.

Otherwise you could try creating your own ITemplate and setting it as the property of the LayoutTemplate for the Login control.

Alternately you could rewrite the generated HTML with an IHttpHandler, or even redo it on the client with something like jQuery dom replacement.